# Disable generation and publishing of pom with gradle

Tags: maven, gradle

For various reasons, I want to publish my zip artifact but not a pom file.  I'm currently using `gradle` with the `maven-publish` plugin (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html).

Is there a way to disable the publish of the pom file?